# UISearchController is visible at view start in a CollectionView with a custom layout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uisearchcontroller

Edit: I changed the custom layout to flow, no changes. So I think the problem is not the custom layout

In my view controller with an embedded navigation controller, I have a CollectionView with a custom layout. In this view controller, I have implemented a UISearchController:

```
// Add searchbar in navigation controller
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.automaticallyShowsCancelButton = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = ""
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

This code works fine for ViewControllers with tables etc, but when I open my view with the CollectionView, the search bar is visible at the start of the view, when it should be only visible by scrolling down.

My constraints for top is at the superview.

I have tried to look at the custom layout code to identify the problem, but was not able to find it.

How can I hide the search bar at view start?

Comment: What’s the value of `navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling`?

Comment: Hi, the value is true